# How do you set mount options for tmpfs volumes?

Tags: 18.04, fstab, tmpfs

I am trying to add the `nodev` option to the `/run` `tmpfs` partition on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system. For other file systems like `/boot` that exist in `/etc/fstab` I can add mount options there. `/run` does not exist in `/etc/fstab` (at least on my system). Where/how do you specify mount options for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the fstab. tmpfs are not normally located here but no harm is done by adding it.

```
vim /etc/fstab # or your chosen editor.
```

Enter this line for /run in this case

```
tmpfs  /run  tmpfs  nodev 0 0
```

Save and exit fstab. Remount the file system.

```
mount -o remount /run
```

perform a rescan/investigation of your issue. It should resolve.